# OpenCv Erosion with specific structure element

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I would like to erode an image with a specific structure element. Default element shapes provided by opencv are ellipse , rectange and cross-shaped.

```
int erosion_type = MORPH_RECT;
Mat element = getStructuringElement(erosion_type,Size(seSize,seSize),
         Point(seSize/2,seSize/2)); 
erode(mat,result,element);
```

What I want is something different. I'd like to erode the image with a specific rectangle like this:

```
00000
00000
11111
00000
00000
```

I tried the following code that alters the structure element data after creating it but it doesn't seem to work. Assuming that the sturcture element is CV_8UC1 and of 5 * 5 shape

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++)
{
    if(i>10 & i < 15)
    data[i] = 0;
    else
    data[i] = 255;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use comma-separated initializer to define any shape for your kernel:

```
cv::Mat element = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(5,5) << 0,0,0,0,0,
                                           0,0,0,0,0,
                                           1,1,1,1,1,
                                           0,0,0,0,0,
                                           0,0,0,0,0);
cv::erode(mat, result, element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Mat src,out;
src = cv::imread('img.jpg',0);

Mat kernel = Mat::zeros(5,5,CV_8U); // 5x5 zero array
kernel.row(2) = 1;                  // set 2nd row to '1'
cv::erode(src,temp0,kernel);        // apply erosion
```